# Band of Misfits copying Feast and then Island

Tags: dominion, dominion-seaside, dominion-dark-ages

I play Throne Room on Band of Misfits and choose Feast.  Since it left play, the next time I play Band of Misfits I can choose a new card, as per this ruling (from the [Complete and All-Encompassing FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Complete_and_All-Encompassing_Dominion_FAQ)):

> If you use Throne Room to play Band of Misfits twice, it will be the
>   chosen card the second time you play it, so you will play it as the
>   same card twice. However, if the card is removed from play (like a
>   Feast), it will be just a Band of Misfits again the second time. You
>   can then choose another Action card from Supply to play it as. The
>   card will stay where it is, and the chosen card's abilities will
>   trigger even as the Band of Misfits will immidiately revert back to
>   being just Band of Misfits (since it's not in play), but you will
>   resolve the triggered abilites of the card.

What if I choose Island for the second use?  I don't think Band of Misfits has lost track of itself, so it seems like it should be able to move itself from the trash to your Island mat.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of September 2019, Band of Misfits has received [official errata](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=19892) that changes its behavior in regards to this question.

The new text for Band of Misfits is:

> Play a non-Command Action card from the Supply that costs less than this, leaving it there.

So Band of Misfits no longer "becomes" another card, instead each time you play it, it causes you to play another card from the supply without that card moving from the supply.

This means that when you use Band of Misfits to play a Feast, the Band of Misfits is no longer trashed. And neither is the Feast because the effect expects Feast to be in play but it isn't. And when you use it to play an Island, you will set aside a card from your hand onto the Island Mat, but neither the Band of Misfits nor the Island will get set aside.

So the new result of Throne Room + Band of Misfits choosing Feast and then Island is:

- Play Throne Room

  - Play Band of Misfits

    - Play a Feast from the Supply

      - Gain a card costing up to $5
  - Play Band of Misfits (again)

    - Play an Island from the Supply

      - Choose a card from your hand to put on your Island Mat

Comment: So whenever a card is played, it always assumes it's in play at that point, and if not, then it's already lost track of itself?

Comment: @codebreaker I think so, yes. For example, Throne Room + Mining Village. If you choose to trash Mining Village the first time it is played, then you cannot trash it again the second time, because it expects itself to be in play. (Though in that case, even without Lose Track you couldn't trash it because to trash it means to move it from somewhere that isn't the trash to the trash).

Comment: That would make sense.  And I actually did think of that example, but I thought the only reason it didn't work was because you can't trash a card already in the trash.

Comment: @codebreaker I have asked your question over at dominionstrategy, where Donald himself will hopefully answer soon; as I'm not 100% sure I'm correct.

Comment: Also if you care about the actions in your deck, using the BoM as an Island first, then a Feast will let you keep the BoM on your island.

Comment: @codebreaker Edited with quote and link confirming my answer.